# "Lets talk about the disadvantages, the first one being...."

Tags: word-choice

So I heard this sentence of someone who was clearly a native speaker

> Lets talk about the disadvantages, the first one **being**....

and he chose it instead of

> Lets talk about the disadvantages, the first one **is**...."

which is what I would have gone with in such a sentence. So of course, I want to know why.

Comment: Both sentences have the same meaning, it's stylistic.

Comment: If you could hear punctuation, and the speaker used a colon instead of a comma, it would be exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: @Chandthunder Could you tell us what words come after 'being' and 'is' in both of those sentences ? It would be easier to understand for us.

Comment: Could you provide complete sentences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's talk about the disadvantages, the first one is the ketchup covering the cucumbers.

Believe it or not, this is incorrect.  It's a run-on sentence.  Instead of the comma to connect two independent clauses, there should be either a semicolon or a period, separating it into two sentences.  Both of these are clunky and awkward.  But there's a smoother way to do it.'

> Let's talk about the disadvantages, the first one being the ketchup covering the cucumbers.

Not only is this grammatically correct (being the ketchup... is a participial phrase modifying one, an appositive), it's smooth and easy to say.

Comment: The correct form is an _absolute_ clause.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction